# How to properly add an ADO.NET data model to a Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Coming from `WinForms`, I am a total beginner in ASP.NET and WEB API. I've started by creating an empty Web API project in Visual Studio. Now I would like to connect it to my already existing database.

In WinForms, I will typically have a separate class library - data access layer or something like that, where I can have the `.edmx` file.

Now in the current project, I have the `Models` folder. I am not sure what is the proper way to do it, but I can see that I can create my data model there. Is that the way to go?

And a second question: am I also supposed to create other model classes in this folder?

I mean that in the database I might have a Students table with lets say 20 columns, but in my project I might have a case where I might need an instance of Students with just two properties (it's not the best example...i know).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a project for your entities with `Entity Framework`. When you right click on the project you can select Add new -> ADO.NET Entity data model. Then you can either pick design from database or code first from database. Although design is easier I recommend code first because it's more flexible and from EF7 on EDMX is no longer supported.
2. Create a second project for your api. You can do this by first adding a ASP.NET Web Application and in the second screen select Web API. You can then add `Web API 2 Controller using Entity Framework`.
3. Reference your entities project in your web api.

You can find more information on the web api with Entity framework [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-1).

Comment: To add to this. The Web API models folder is for more of a dumbed down look into your entity framework entities. For example, if you have property that is required for database but not for Web API then the Class in the Models Folder would not have that property.

Comment: Thanks for the info! @ShaunSharples Also thanks for the additional information, that's exactly what I was thinking, but I wasn't sure.